# Computing sum of linear sequence modulo n

Tags: algorithm, sum, modulo

I'm looking to calculate the following sum efficiently:

sum (i=0..max) (i * A mod B)

One may assume that max, A < B and that A and B are co-prime (otherwise an easy reduction is possible). Numbers are large, so simple iteration is way too inefficient.
So far I haven't been able to come up with a polynomial-time algorithm (i.e., polynomial in log(B)), best I could find is O(sqrt(max)). Is this a known hard problem, or does anyone know of a polynomial-time algorithm?

To be clear, the "mod B" only applies to the i*A, not to the overall sum. So e.g.

sum(i=0..3) (i*7 mod 11) = 0 + 7 + 3 + 10 = 20.

Comment: out of curiosity, what's the O(sqrt(max)) solution?

Comment: A bit complex, but in a nutshell you break up the sum into linear sequences of values (up to sqrt(max) of them), and apply the triangle rule for summation for each such linear sub-sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You can shift things around a bit to get

```
 A*(sum(i=0..max)) mod B
```

which simplifies to

```
 A*(max*(max+1)/2) mod B
```

Now you only need to do one (possibly big-int) multiplication (assuming max itself isn't too big) followed by one (big-int) mod operation.

Comment: You can still use the fact that `(x * y) mod B = (x mod B) * (y mod B) mod B`, which solves the big subresult of the multiplication.

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear with my question - the modulo B only applies to the individual values, not to the entire sum.